# PictureBox for Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, picturebox

Hi im currently using a Windows Store App Project and is using this code below. However I realised that Metro app doesnt support WinForm. Is there any control that is able to substitute picturebox in Metro? If im wrong in any way, feel free to correct me.

```
bool spectrum3DVoicePrint = _visuals.CreateSpectrum3DVoicePrint(_handle, pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(), pictureBox1.Bounds, Color.Cyan, Color.Green,_pos, false, true);
```

**Edit:** 
I realise that metro doesnt support System.Windows.Media.Color as well. the 3 problems that i currently face is
1) pictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
2) pictureBox1.Bounds
3) Color.color

Comment: Have you tried [`<Image />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242752) control ?

Comment: Hi i have tried it but it does not provide .CreateGraphics() that is only available in WinForms as im using a metro app. Likewise to Colour.color .

Comment: What do you want to achieve, update your question with your scenario/requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i think there is not an alternative to picturebox for winrt or uwp.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good decade of disconnect between WinForms and WinRT Xaml. I think instead of trying to do a line by line port, you need to understand what you are trying to do and do something similar in Xaml.